# how can i read multiple image folders?

Tags: python, glob, face-recognition

i want to encoding some of folders that contain face images.

this is the code that i've been tried.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
known_face_encodings = []
known_face_names = []

# Load  image folder and learn how to recognize it.
os.chdir("./coba1")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    images = face_recognition.load_image_file(file)
    images_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(images)[0]
    known_face_encodings.append(images_encoding)
    known_face_names.append("jokowi")
    print(images_encoding)

#Load image folder and learn how to recognize it.
os.chdir("./coba")
for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    images = face_recognition.load_image_file(file)
    images_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(images)[0]
    known_face_encodings.append(images_encoding)
    known_face_names.append("amber heard")
    print(images_encoding)
```

when i run the code, the terminal shows this warning

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "face_rec.py", line 32, in <module>
    os.chdir("./coba")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './coba'
```

is there anything wrong with my code? i really need the solution, thanks in advance !

Comment: Looks like you forgot to go one level up to the parent folder again. Alternatively you could add the subfolder to your glob.

Comment: i solved my problem with your solution. thank you